# Testing Twitter with Spark Streaming API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, spark-streaming

I am new to Streaming framework of Spark and was trying to process the twitter stream.
I am in process of writing test cases for same and understand that I can use Spark StreamingSuiteBase which will help me test input as a stream on my functions. 
But I have written a function which take DStream[Status] as input and after processing gives DStream[String] as output.
The api I am using from StreamingSuiteBase is testOperation.

```
test("Filter only words Starting with #")  {
  val inputTweet = List(List("this is #firstHash"), List("this is #secondHash"), List("this is #thirdHash"))
  val expected = List(List("#firstHash"), List("#secondHash"), List("#thirdHash"))

  testOperation(inputTweet, TransformTweets.getText _, expected, ordered = false)
```

And this is the function on which the input is sent..

```
 def getText(englishTweets: DStream[Status]): DStream[String] = {
    println(englishTweets.toString)

    val hashTags = englishTweets.flatMap(x => x.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))

    hashTags
  }
```

But I am getting the error "type mismatch" due to DStream[Status] and DStream[String]. How do I mock Stream[Status].

Comment: Why are your tweets list of lists?

Comment: And you should unit test the flatMap operation on a list of statuses, not need to mock a Dstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved this issue by getting the Twitter status from "`createStatus`" API of `TwitterObjectFactory`. There was no need to mock `TwitterStatus`. Even if you manage to mock it there are Serialization issues. So, this is the best solution:

```
val rawJson = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/tweetStatus.json")).getLines.mkString
val tweetStatus = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(rawJson)
```

Hope this helps someone !